# Int literal in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying out code examples from the book "The Craft of Functional Programming".

I want to create a Tree that has `Int`s in it but I seem to ended up creating a Tree with Integers in it (please see execution in GHCi below).

How can I create a Tree with `Int`s in it ? Is there a way to write an `Int` literal in Haskell ?

```
*Chapter18> sumTree myTree

<interactive>:35:9:
    Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'
    Expected type: Tree Int
      Actual type: Tree Integer
    In the first argument of `sumTree', namely `myTree'
    In the expression: sumTree myTree
    In an equation for `it': it = sumTree myTree
```

Here is the corresponding code:

```
-- A type of binary trees.
myTree = Node 2 (Nil) (Nil)

data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

-- Summing a tree of integers

-- A direct solution:

sTree :: Tree Int -> Int

sTree Nil            = 0
sTree (Node n t1 t2) = n + sTree t1 + sTree t2

-- A monadic solution: first giving a value of type Id Int ...

sumTree :: Tree Int -> Id Int

sumTree Nil = return 0

--sumTree (Node n t1 t2)
--  = do num <- return n
--       s1  <- sumTree t1
--       s2  <- sumTree t2
--       return (num + s1 + s2)
sumTree (Node n t1 t2) =
    return n >>=(\num ->
      sumTree t1 >>= (\s1 ->
        sumTree t2 >>= (\s2 ->
          return (num + s1 + s2))))
-- ... then adapted to give an Int solution



sTree' :: Tree Int -> Int

sTree' = extract . sumTree

-- where the value is extracted from the Id monad thus:

extract :: Id a -> a
extract (Id x) = x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) strikes again! Because `myTree` doesn't have any arguments, the compiler avoids making it polymorphic. But the numerical literal is polymorphic (there are no `Int` literals, only integral `Num` literals!), so the compiler needs to decide upon some `Num` type. Well, `Int` could be a problem if you're dealing with huge numbers, so it chooses `Integer`.

Giving `myTree` an explicit signature would have prevented that; either use

```
myTree :: Num a => Tree a
```

Or

```
myTree :: Tree Int
```